# Using Input from Worksheet in a Query in a Macro

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am trying to take the percent column, column 3, from the "input" file and use that to take a discount on a price and put that price in the output file, one by one in column 7.

I pass the SQL connection to a function, a UPC value that looks up information in a database, and then the percent value (a Double) as input.

However, I keep getting the error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword percent". I have tried renaming the percent variable, and also using the Val() function (as you can see in the code).

If I take the Val() out, I get a type mismatch error

*Basically*: I cannot figure out how to use an input for "percent" such as .10 in my Query.

```vb
 For i = 1 To 381
     wrkb.Worksheets("Output").Cells(i + 1, 2).CopyFromRecordset extractInfo(cnn, wrkb.Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 2).Value, Val(wrkb.Worksheets("Input").Cells(i, 3).Value))
Next i


Function extractInfo(cnn As ADODB.Connection, upc As String, percent As Double) As ADODB.Recordset

'Initializes variables

Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim StrQuery As String

'The query to run, feed the UPC value you acquired to then get all the other variables
StrQuery = "SELECT 'N' as Division, zzeupcnr.style as Style, color_code as Color, ' ' as label_code, dimension as Dimension, ROUND((a_price * (1.00 - percent)), 2), ret_price " & _
        "FROM zzeupcnr JOIN zzxstylr " & _
        "ON zzeupcnr.style = zzxstylr.style " & _
        "WHERE upc = '" & upc & "'"

'Performs the actual query
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

Set extractInfo = rst 'Stores result
```

Comment: Have you tried `ROUND((a_price * (1.00 - " & percent & ")), 2)` instead of `ROUND((a_price * (1.00 - percent)), 2)`?

Comment: What is the data type of the field in the SQL table?

Comment: @Mistella yes I have, that did not work, still gave me a type mismatch

Comment: @Jaberwocky I have the call to extractInfo() inside the for loop, the SQL table should have doubles in there

Comment: Have you tried substituting a hard-coded value to verify that the SQL works as intended?

Comment: @Mistella yup! the SQL works, for instance if I have ROUND(a_price - (a_price * .10), 2), it works just fine. It takes 10% off and puts it in the output file

Comment: Is this using SQL/SSMS server? If so why not use debug to copy the content of StrQuery into SSMS and run the query here. You can then play around with the syntax until it works correctly.

Comment: Also consider using actual ADODB command and parameters instead of concatenating parameter values into your command string.

Comment: Percent is a keyword, so I definitely wouldn't suggest using it as a field-name. Also, you haven't given the *output field* a name?

Comment: I have tried both changing the name of the variable and also [percent]. The query works completely fine with a hard coded value but there is a just a data type issue which I can't figure out how to fix

Comment: This is getting to far.  Judging by the actual error, the problem is in the VBA code, not in the query.  Check the cell type and make sure that matches up with your data type.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear the previous comment was based on the mismatch error, not the original error.  @Shania It would always be helpful for you to step through your code so you can tell people where it's failing as well.  The first error you mentioned sounds like an SQL error, the second one is definitely a VBA error.  All that being said, you need to set up error traps in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `percent` in your query string as a string.

If you want to use the variable value, you need to do this:

```vb
StrQuery = "SELECT 'N' as Division, zzeupcnr.style as Style, color_code as Color, ' ' as label_code, dimension as Dimension, ROUND((a_price * (1.00 - " & percent & ")), 2), ret_price " & _
        "FROM zzeupcnr JOIN zzxstylr " & _
        "ON zzeupcnr.style = zzxstylr.style " & _
        "WHERE upc = '" & upc & "'"
```

Note the `" & percent & "`

Comment: 3...2...1... waiting for a joke for Mr.Null and Mrs.Null.

Comment: @Vityata What's the joke?  I like jokes :)

Comment: This one - https://xkcd.com/327/ . It is considered a bad practice to concatenate variables in SQL. The good practice is to pass it as a parameter, thus to avoid possible SQL injection.

Comment: Hah, I like that one :)

Comment: For the good practice, you may refer to this article - https://www.vitoshacademy.com/automagic-secure-adodb/ , written by @Mathieu (also present in the comments of the Q here) - disclaimer - the site is mine.

Comment: Gosh I completely missed that `percent` was a local. +1 ...though, as noted above, this code is vulnerable to malicious UPC strings.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon any +1s I get from you is like +1000 in my books ;)